# I don’t see the Buid and Analyze option in my Build Option in Xcode

Tags: xcode, static-analysis

I am trying to use the Clang static analyzer in my code. I installed it and can run it succesfully from the terminal. But I wanted see it locally on the code not on Safari. The resort [sic] is to activate Build And Analyze in Build Options, which I dont see at all. Help me with this. Any clear step by step procedure for Clang's installation?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably using Xcode 3.1.x and reading documentation for Xcode 3.2.  In the earlier version you had to download Clang, run it from the command line, and view the results as HTML.  In Xcode 3.2 it's all built-in and you choose Build and Analyze from the Build menu.  If you don't see that menu item, you're probably using the earlier version of Xcode.

Xcode 3.2 only runs on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard, by the way, and requires an Intel-based Mac.